# Making a c++ project with OpenCV on Eclipse on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu

I have a problem to create a c++ project with OpenCV on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
I followed the steps in the tutorial and set all path written in here; http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html#linux-eclipse-usage

However, I when tried to build all for DisplayImage.cpp in the website, eclipse returns following errors to me. I have got no idea to solve this issue. I would appreciate if you could solve this/help me on this.
Thank you so much.

```
20:23:27 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project opencv_test3 ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/DisplayImage.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/DisplayImage.d" -MT"src/DisplayImage.o" -o "src/DisplayImage.o" "../src/DisplayImage.cpp"
../src/DisplayImage.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../src/DisplayImage.cpp:16:30: error: ‘imread’ was not declared in this scope
   image = imread( argv[1], 1 );
                              ^
../src/DisplayImage.cpp:24:52: error: ‘namedWindow’ was not declared in this scope
   namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
                                                    ^
../src/DisplayImage.cpp:25:34: error: ‘imshow’ was not declared in this scope
   imshow( "Display Image", image );
                                  ^
../src/DisplayImage.cpp:27:12: error: ‘waitKey’ was not declared in this scope
   waitKey(0);
            ^
make: *** [src/DisplayImage.o] Error 1

20:23:28 Build Finished (took 484ms)
```

Comment: it is actually "including" the opencv folder... are you sure that `/usr/local/include/opencv` exists and has the include files of opencv? also, what is your code? are you including `#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>` ?

Comment: yes, the path is valid and there are files I need to include. and there are also headers you mentioned in my code. Thanks,